# Intent and activity back on Android

Tags: android, android-intent

I have 2 activities: A, B:
The A will launch B.
But I want to let B click "Back" button can back to desktop, but not back to A activity.
I use below code to start activity:

```
Intent NewActivity = new Intent();
NewActivity.setClass(A.this, B.class);
NewActivity.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
startActivity(NewActivity);
```

But while click back button, it still back to A activity.
How can I do it?

Comment: Have you tried cleaning your project and rebuilding? Delete the app from the device and reinstall?

Comment: after startActivity(NewActivity); write A.this.finish();

Comment: or you can use `NewActivity.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);` while starting the B activity

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add finish() when you start the activity.

```
Intent NewActivity = new Intent();
NewActivity.setClass(A.this, B.class);
NewActivity.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
startActivity(NewActivity);
finish();
```

Answer (score 1):

Then I suppose you are aiming at finishing all the stacked up activity..

Here it is :-

Closing all the previous activities as follows:

`Intent intent = new Intent(A.this, B.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
intent.putExtra("Exit me", true);
startActivity(intent);
finish();`
Then in B's `onCreate()` method add this to finish the B

`if( getIntent().getBooleanExtra("Exit me", false)){
    finish();
}`

or else if you simply going back from present activity, definitely your application goes to home just becz your stack is empty.

The result will be same as above, but because all your stacked up activities are closed, when you come back to you app it must start from your main activity i.e launcher activity.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Try this flag for this :

```
 intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
```

Answer (score 0):

When you have started the new activity, you can also finish() the current activity like this in activity A:

```
startActivity(new Intent(curentClass.this, newClass.class));
finish();
```

Comment: Never use this! This is make you're activity destroyed when you locked phone etc.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a good thing to do. The typical user experience is, that they will go back to the previous activity, by pressing the back button. That is why there is a back- and home button on each device. The android guidelines states, that is the correct behaviour.

But if you want to do it anyway, you'll have to override the following method:

```
void onBackPressed()
```

That'll do the trick. Just start the MAIN Intent here, and you're done.

Comment: Wanting to not let the user simply go back may be a valid design decision of thought of carefully. However, overwriting the back button press is usually a bad practice. Program flow should be handled by the stack and manipulations thereof.

Comment: I agree with @EricTobias - overriding `onBackPressed()` is something which should only be done in certain circumstances and only if you know what you're doing.

Answer (score 0):

To get back to home screen ie desktop

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(intent);
```

finish() will just take u to your first screen ie A!